# Anyways to create a zip file in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

Is there any ways to create a zip archive with apex class?
I have been researching but seems like there is no way with apex class.

So far what i find is this one which is client side options.

http://www.valnavjo.com/blog/compressing-files-in-salesforce/

Comment: I ended up creating zip on external server. We wanted to zip up images stored on the S3. We developed servlet on the heroku to grab the images from S3

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't create zip files directly from apex code.

Answer (score 1):

I've created an app that will allow you to compress files in Salesforce:

http://www.valnavjo.com/blog/bzip-the-app/

You can install it from the AppExchange.

Regards,

Valnavjo